# sed - change lines that start with one given word and end with another?

Tags: sed

For example, given:

```
$ cat test001.txt
this
is a
 test bucket
bucket line not this one.
  bucket lein endy
    bucket and others endy
and
a ttest
```

How can I change the lines that start with "bucket" with "(bucket", ignoring spaces?

So far I have:

```
sed -i 's/^\sbucket/bucket(/g' test001.txt
```

but that doesn't work (no change and no error). Then I would like to only do it for lines that *also* end with 'endy' (so only 2 of the 3 bucket lines).

Comment: Also end with 'endy': `sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*bucket.*endy/(bucket/g' test001.txt`. `.` for any character and `*` for zero or more (greedy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*bucket.*endy$/s/bucket/(bucket/' file.txt
```

The initial `/pattern/` tells sed to only work on lines containing that `pattern`, and the rest of it is a simple, standard substitution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use back references (e.g., `\1`) in your replacement-term which will replace subexpressions (things enclosed within escaped parentheses — `\(…\)`) in your search term.
E.g.,

```
$ cat test001.txt | sed -e 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)\(bucket.*endy\)$/\1(\2/'
this
is a
 test bucket
bucket line not this one.
  (bucket lein endy
    (bucket and others endy
and
a ttest
```

will create two subexpressions:

1. the leading spaces: `^\([[:space:]]*\)`
2. the string that starts with "bucket" and ends with "endy" (at the EOL): `\(bucket.*endy\)$`

It will then replace any line that matches with `\1(\2`, which is the whitespace, followed by an opening parenthesis, followed by the bucket..endy string.

Answer (score 1):

The `\s` is not part of BRE, which `sed` uses. In BRE `\s` is the same as a literal `s`. The equivalent of `\s` would be `[[:space:]]`. Try the following:

```
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*bucket/(bucket/g' test001.txt
```

Comment: Just realize BRE stands for [Basic Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html#tag_007_003).